# C# возврат с потока

Tags: c#, .net

```
public static string pingAllChildren(string myIp)
        {
            object locker = new object();
            string res = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
            {
                int j = i;
                Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    string ip = myIp.Remove(myIp.LastIndexOf('.'), myIp.Length - myIp.LastIndexOf('.')) + $".{j + 10}";

                    IPStatus t = await pingAsync($"{ip}");
                    lock (locker)
                    {
                        res += $"{ip} : {t.ToString()}\n";
                    }
                }).Wait();
                //string ip = myIp.Remove(myIp.LastIndexOf('.'), myIp.Length - myIp.LastIndexOf('.')) + $".{j + 10}";
                //ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(pingAsync(ip));
            }
            return res;
        }
```

если `Wait()` уберу, то возвратиться пустой результат. А так никакой асинхронности.

> Как мне дождаться выполнения всех потоков, чтобы возвратить результат нормально?

Comment: Собираешь в массив все свои таски и ждёшь Task.WaitAll(массив)

Comment: И лучше использовать разные res, а потом уже собрать результат из тасков и заджойнить

Comment: @adrug Чёт провтыкал этот момент, спасибо

Comment: Выкиньте полностью `Task.Run`. Метод `pingAsync` возвращает таску, вот эти таски и складывайте в массив (лист). Потом ожидайте их завершения `Task.Wait`. В итоге все пинги выполняются параллельно. При этом не создается ни одного лишнего потока. При этом не нужна блокировка: выкиньте `lock`.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov а блокировка почему не нужна? Если одновременно два потока будут писать в переменную, то что получится?

Comment: А откуда они у вас возьмутся, одновременные потоки? Вы же пинги последовательно отправляете...

Comment: Ну дак вопрос для того и задаю, чтобы запаралеллить их.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На мой взгляд лучше было бы сделать так:

```
public static string pingAllChildren(string myIp)
{
    var pings = Enumerable.Range(1, 4).Select(i =>
             myIp.Remove(myIp.LastIndexOf('.'), myIp.Length - myIp.LastIndexOf('.')) + $".{i + 10}")
        .Select(ip => new { ip, task = pingAsync(ip) }).ToList();

    Task.WaitAll(pings.Select(p => p.task).ToArray());

    return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, pings.Select(p => $"{p.ip} : {p.task.Result}"));
}
```

Сначала создаем нужные нам IP и запускаем таску пинга. Помещаем это в анонимный объект, чтобы потом не потерять пингуемый IP. Далее происходит ожидание всех задач из массива и только после этого через `string.Join` мы создаем форматированный результат.

Comment: почему бы тогда не сделать всю функцию асинхронной?

Comment: Тогда где вызов будет придется исправить ещё)

Comment: что автор сейчас и делает, если поглядеть на принятый ответ :)